# Put Django view return data into response data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a function based view and it has many checks in it and returns data based on check results. So I don't want to wrap my data into [Response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/) object every time manually. Is there a way to put function return value into OK response data automatically in Django Rest Framework? For example to have a valid view like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def pre_reg_countries(request):
    if some_condition:
        return data_1  # instead of returning Response(data=data_1)
    else:
        if another condition:
            return data_2
        else:
            return []
```

P.S. The idea came to me from Java Spring framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Django does not provide some built-in solution, a decorator like this can solve the problem:

```
def responsify(view_method):
    def add_response(*args, **kwargs):
        data = view_method(*args, **kwargs)
        return Response(data)
    return add_response
```